# Executing a python script in Ubuntu defaults to shell and not bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am running a python script in Ubuntu which relies on packages being installed. These are all installed as i can invoke them, but the script cannot.

I think this is because the script is using shell(sh) and not the bash version.i get this error message out:

```
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
```

but can invoke genomeCoverageBed manually in Bash:

```
ubuntu@fat:~/jonathan/scripty$ genomeCoverageBed 


Tool:    bedtools genomecov (aka genomeCoverageBed)
Version: v2.26.0

Summary: Compute the coverage of a feature file among a genome.
```

This part of my Stackoverflow question is misleading and wrong!:

> I have added this shebang to the start of my python script:
>
> #!/bin/bash
>
> But this has not affected the outcome,

Taking this out of my script still causes the same error messages
Here is part of the script:

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
if filename.endswith(".sorted.bam"):
    namefile = filename.replace(".sorted.bam", "_ncoverage.txt")
    folder_name = filename.replace(".sorted.bam", "")
    os.system("mkdir " + folder_name)
    os.system("coverageBed -s -d -a bam " + folder + filename + " -b " + gff_file + " > " + folder_name + "/" + namefile)
```

Here is what happens when i run this script:

```
ubuntu@fat:~/jonathan/script$ sudo python2.7 script1.py ./Folder/ ./Folder/ref.fasta genbank.gff
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: coverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
sh: genomeCoverageBed: command not found
```

Do you have any suggestions about what i can do, or even if i am on the right track?
thanks for your help!

Comment: Um, you put `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the python script? That runs a subshell, not python.

Comment: Exactly in what language is your script written, `python` or `bash`??

Comment: This script is written in python

Comment: but then why do you put `#!/bin/bash` as a first line?? If it is a python script put something like `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: But i added that line as some sort of fix, clearly your telling me that fix is wrong! but the same result occurs without that line

Comment: You can type `which python` in your terminal, whatever comes back (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`) you should put as a shebang in the first line.

Comment: Show an example of executing the script in python. Not just the error message.

Comment: Your example runs `coverageBed` not `genomeCoverageBed`... working code would be great! Something crazy small like `import os;os.system("genomeCoverageBed")` would demonstrate the problem. How do you run this script? From the command line? `os.system(..)` should be able to run the same commands you run on the shell so there has to be something different going on in your script. That's why I want to see the smallest possible script  - to rule everything else out. We don't need loops or anything else. Just the command.

Comment: the script runs both coverageBed and genomeCoverageBed. I can run both of those myself with no problem. I have edited my original post  how i run it. and also i have included the main part of the script.

Comment: The `sudo` may be your problem. When you `sudo` you run in a different environment and it may not be able to find your program. From the shell, does the sudo work? That is, `ubuntu@fat:~/jonathan/scripty$ sudo genomeCoverageBed`?

Comment: YES! that must be it! When i run "sudo genomeCoverageBed" it is not found. Now how do i get around this? the python file is creating and moving files, it requires sudo

Comment: In a regular shell, use `type genomeCoverageBed` to see what kind of command it is (alias, function or executable). If it's an executable in a non-standard location, you can just use absolute path, e.g. `/home/you/bin/genomeCoverageBed`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong shebang

```
#!/bin/bash
```

When a linux shell is asked to run a text file (e.g., `./myprogram.py`), it looks at the shebang to figure out which program should be used to interpret the text. In your case you asked the shell to run `/bin/bash` - another shell and it tried to interpret the python script as a shell script.

You can write the shebang differently

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This tells the shell to run `/usr/bin/env` which will search the PATH for a thing called `pythnon3`. Now, you run the python setup for your current environment. By default its the system python but if you run in a python virtual environment, it runs *that* python.

The shebang is only used on linuxy systems and is only used when you make a script executable and run it directly. If running on windows (outside of cygwin or other unix-like shell) or running python directly (`python /path/to/myscript.py`) then its not used.

Comment: To confirm, i am trying to execture a python script in a bash enviroment, yeah? I normally run the script as follows: sudo python2.7 script.py

Comment: Your last comment is the most important for me. You only use shebang to make a script exectuable and run it directly. I have misled you and others by including my erroneous quick fix '#!/bin/bash'. The original problem still stands

Comment: @JonathanAbrahams Can you post a small example of your failing python script? Just hack it to a few lines that demonstrate the problem and post that - plus a full stack trace if applicable -  in your question. Then we can work through the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your shebang is calling a subshell, as @tdelaney mentioned in the comments. You need to use something like the following to use python as the program executing the file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu won't run the python file in python if you put #!/bin/bash , that will open in bash. Try putting #!/usr/bin/python or #!/usr/bin/env python

Answer (score 0):

I followed this post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path

and added:

sudo env "PATH=$PATH"

to the start of my command and this solved my issue!

Thanks to all who helped!